# Normal (Regular) or Inverted Terms?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecular-mechanics

I have a question on the order of the spin-orbit molecular states. I understand how to find the terms that split from a parent molecular state in a diatomic molecule. But my question is on how to find whether the multiplet states are normal (regular) or inverted. For example, if we take $^3\Pi$, this state will split into $^3\Pi_{0^+}$, $^3\Pi_{0^-}$, $^3\Pi_1$, and $^3\Pi_2$. How can we know the order of these states, that is to say normal (regular) or inverted? If they are in this order: $^3\Pi_{0^+}$, $^3\Pi_{0^-}$, $^3\Pi_1$, and $^3\Pi_2$; or in that order: $^3\Pi_2$, $^3\Pi_1$, $^3\Pi_{0^-}$, and $^3\Pi_{0^+}$.

In Spectra of Diatomic Molecules book, by Herzberg, he pointed out these terms, and gave the following equation:
$$T_e=T_0+A\Lambda\Sigma$$
where $A$ is a constant for a given multiplet term.
He also stated that if $A$ is positive, this will give rise to normal (regular) terms. However, if $A$ is negative, we get inverted terms.
So is there another way to find out other than this way? And by the way, how can we determine $A$?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: What page is this on? I looked but could not find it from the index on spin orbit.

Comment: Pages 215 and 216

Comment: In case that you can get your hands on a copy of Brown and Carrington's "Rotational Spectroscopy of Diatomic Molecules" you should check out section 7.8.3 (page 357) where they discuss a simple orbital model to estimate the value of the spin-orbit parameter.